# how to remove occurrences in python string independently of cap size with possible punctuation?

Tags: python, string

I have a string similar to:

```
newstr = 'Some text shown in fig.1 which I've extracted from a pdf\n using the method by thisguy et al, (see Fig)\n which was previously shown by otherguy Et Al.\n using whatever et al.'
```

I want to extract all occurrences of 'fig' and 'et al' independently of cap size and trailing punctuation, i.e. 'fig','Fig','FIG','et al','et al.' etc. Those args are passed as a list:

```
removespecial= ['fig','et al']
```

of course, a real list could contain many more elements.

Because of cap size I cannot simply use:

```
for element in removelist:
    newstr = ' '.join(newstr.split(element))
```

unless I define all possible variations of what I could be expected to have, which I definitely want to avoid.

**What would be the best way to do this ?**

So far, I've come up with a pretty ugly solution:

```
if removespecial:
    for element in removespecial:
        #element has to be one word of the sentence i.e. with space before and after
        #but also take into account possible string punctuation immediately after, e.g. fig. or et al.

        #because of cap size, can't use join/split method here
        if element in newstr.lower():
            #init
            elementindlist = []
            #get all indexes of occurrences
            elementindlistinit = [[m.start(),m.end()] for m in re.finditer(element, newstr.lower())]

            #go through all the index list to check whether general conditions are satisfied
            for i in range(len(elementindlistinit)):

                #check that there is a space before or is the beginning of a sentence
                if elementindlistinit[i][0] == 0 or newstr[elementindlistinit[i][0]-1] in string.whitespace:

                    #check if there is a string punctuation immediately after, e.g. fig. or et al.
                    #if last character is end of line simply append
                    if elementindlistinit[i][1] == len(newstr):
                        elementindlist.append(elementindlistinit[i])

                    #otherwise, element must be followed by a whitespace (full word) or punctuation
                    else:
                        if newstr[elementindlistinit[i][1]] in string.punctuation + string.whitespace:
                            elementindlist.append([elementindlistinit[i][0],elementindlistinit[i][1]+1])

                ##should aslo remove trailing number..

            #if valid elements have been found crop string accordingly
            if len(elementindlist) > 0:   
                tempstr = ''
                if elementindlist[0][0] != 0:
                    tempstr += newstr[0:elementindlist[0][0]]

                for i in range(len(elementindlist)-1):
                    tempstr += newstr[elementindlist[i][1]:elementindlist[i+1][0]]

                if elementindlist[-1][-1] != len(newstr)-1:
                    tempstr += newstr[elementindlist[-1][1]:-1]
                newstr = tempstr
```

print newstr returns:

```
Some text shown in 1 which I ve extracted from a pdf
using the method by thisguy  (see 
which was previously shown by otherguy 
using whatever
```

This works, but I'm can't help thinking that there must be a much more elegant solution using e.g. regular expressions but I couldn't come up with a correct code for this...

Any idea ?
[using python 2.7 but I don't think this matters much (?)]

Comment: Have a look into Regular Expressions

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
re.sub(r'et al|fig', '', your_string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Or something like this. Of course you should tweak this regex a little to prevent some unnecessary spaces/dots/etc

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure regular expression are the right way to go, but if I test this on my string, I get: _Some text shown in .1 which I ve extracted from a pdf
 using the method by thisguy , (see )
 which was previously shown by otherguy .
 using whatever ._ The killer, here is that I'm left will all the punctuation which, in a text mining application is not a very good thing... I could easily get rid of all the punctuation after this, but then, I loose the original sentence structure.

Comment: @Aure just put whatever you want in the match string:
`re.sub(r'et al\W*|fig\W*', '', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))`
etc (\W is for non-word character). Should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [nltk tokenize](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html). Then you can do something like this:

```
import string
from nltk import word_tokenize

def process_line(text, stopwords):
    tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    filtered_tokens = [token for token in tokens 
                       if token not in string.punctuation 
                           and token.lower() not in stopwords]
    return ' '.join(filtered_tokens)

processed_text = '\n'.join([process_line(line, removespecial) 
                            for line in newstr.split('\n')])
```

This may not meet your exact needs (in particular, note that multiple spaces will be replaced by single spaces), but this is the kind of task that nltk is good for.

Comment: Thanks, seems like an interesting way to go. I'll check this out and post some feedback asap.